# After dynamically add item, it adds outside owl-stage-outer

Tags: jquery, vue.js, owl-carousel

I am facing strange issue 
I have created a carousel which loops through via vuejs.

```
<div class="owl-carousel unitslide">
  <div  v-for="unit in sortedUnits" class="unit" :class="{selected : activeUnit.id === unit.id}" @click="activeUnit = unit">
     @{{  unit.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```

So after load, above code looks like this.

```
<div class="owl-carousel unitslide owl-loaded owl-drag">
    <div class="owl-stage-outer">
        <div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0s ease 0s; width: 776px;">
            <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 56.5px; margin-right: 14px;">
                <div class="unit">
                301
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 56.5px; margin-right: 14px;">
                <div class="unit">
                    400
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-nav">
        <button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-prev disabled">
            <div class="arrow left"></div>
        </button>
        <button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-next">
            <div class="arrow right"></div>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-dots disabled"></div>
</div>
```

After adding  some more unit dynamically via vuejs new item add below owl-dots disabled tag like this

```
<div class="owl-dots disabled"></div>
<div class="unit">501</div>
<div class="unit">502</div>
```

owl carousel not wrapping new items in

```
<div class="owl-item active"></div>
```

Owl carousel js is this:

```
$(".unitslide").owlCarousel({
        margin:14,
        items:4,
        loop:false,
        autoWidth:false,
        dots:false,
        nav: true,
        navText: ["<div class='arrow left'></div>","<div class='arrow right'></div>"]

    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean by 'After adding some more unit dynamically via vuejs new item add below owl-dots disabled tag like this'. Could you rephrase this please?

Comment: Initially there are few units which is in carousel, but when i add more data (units) which is added automatically that units generate outside .owl-stage-outer element

Answer (score 0):

```
<div v-if=showTopStore >
   <carousel class="carousel-inner" :autoplay="false" :nav="false" :items="1">
       <div v-for="(store, key) in allStore" class="item" >
           <mobile-store-card :store="store" ></mobile-store-card>
       </div>
   </carousel>
</div>
```

`showTopStore` is `False` by default and `True` when the data  is fully loaded.